# Do I need to inform the immigration/boarder about my extension for B1/B2 tourist visa since my extension will be less than 6 months?

Tags: usa, tourist-visas

It’s my first time traveling to the US under my tourist visa. My first attempt was rejected and they asked me for more proof and info about my residency in Canada under PR.

I tried to get a ticket again to go to the US for a couple of days with my documents this time and I was approved. My stay here in the US is supposed to be 2 weeks and 3 days and I want to extend my stay here in the US.

Do I need to inform the immigration/border about staying for longer than 2 months? My visa is valid for 6 months and my stay in the US will be less than 6 months.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were admitted for six months, you can stay for up to six months.  You don't need to inform anyone.  Even if you want to do so, you will have a hard time finding anyone to accept that information.

You can check your period of admission at https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov.

However, given your earlier visa refusal, you should be careful.  It's possible that your change of plans could be taken as a deception designed to help your second visa application succeed.  I haven't heard about this happening much in the US, but it is common in the UK.  Given the current US political climate, it might be a good idea to be cautious.

If you can show a credible reason for your change of plans, you probably don't need to worry about this, but if you have just decided that you want to stay longer on a whim, it might be safer to leave the US and return.